# Stop recommending GMail Contacts

Tags: contacts, sync

When I got my LG Tribute, I put in my Google account, and it immediately downloaded all 1700 GMail contacts from my many years of e-mail.

Obviously I don't want all those contacts, so I went to Accounts&Sync and told my phone to not sync contacts with GMail, and then hid all the contacts.

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to truly get rid of them, so they are all in Groups > Other Contacts, taking up space.  More importantly, when I want to type a message or contact someone, there's a search bar that makes recommendations that I select from, which I always use.  But now those recommendations are from my GMail contacts, since they're still on my phone even though they're not in my main contacts list.  so i.e. if I want to talk to my friend Selena and I type "Se", I'll be recommended the e-mail for "ITS Server Admins Group" where I want the contact.

How can I get rid of them once and for all, or at least have them stop showing up everywhere?

Answer (score 1):

i have a samsung, but the steps should be quite similar:

```
Settings > More > Applications > Go right to all apps > scroll down to "Contacts Storage"

Then click on contacts storage > Click Clear Data
```

Hope this helps